# Are there any disadvantages to GraphQL?

Tags: rest, restful-authentication, graphql

All the articles about GraphQL will tell you how wonderful it is, but are there any disadvantages or shortcomings to it? Thank you.

Answer (score 123):

**Disadvantages**:

- You **need to learn** how to set up GraphQL. The ecosystem is still rapidly evolving so you have to keep up.
- You need to send the queries from the client, you can just send strings but if you want more comfort and caching you'll use a client library -> **extra code** in your client
- You need to define the schema beforehand => **extra work** before you get results
- You need to have a graphql endpoint on your server => **new libraries** that you don't know yet
- Graphql queries are **more bytes** than simply going to a REST endpoint
- The server needs to do **more processing** to parse the query and verify the parameters

But, those are more than countered by these **Advantages**:

- GraphQL is **not that hard to learn**
- The extra code is **only a few KB**
- By defining a schema, you will **prevent much more work afterwards** fixing bugs and enduring hairy upgrades
- There are a lot of people switching to GraphQL so there is a **rich ecosystem** developing, with excellent tooling
- When using persistent queries in production (replacing GraphQL queries with simply an ID and parameters), you actually send **fewer bytes** than with REST
- The extra processing for incoming queries is negligible
- Providing a **clean decoupling of API and backend** allows for much faster iteration on backend improvenments

Comment: "You need to define the schema beforehand => extra work before you get results" I don't see how this is not necessary without GraphQL? Sure with some frameworks in some languages it's not required, but for example for a Java API you'll still have to describe the "schema" in your models.

Comment: @AntoineB you are correct, in NodeJS however you can easily make a REST API without ever thinking about the overall schema; just return things.

Comment: @w00t and as soon as you need some parameters with REST, you'll resort to parsing URL an checking that the type of the param is correct, throwing a 400 if it's not. If only there was something to avoid having to do this manually in every route handler :D

Comment: With Spring Boot you can just pull some artifacts `graphql-spring-boot-starter` and `graphql-java-tools` to get started.  Create your schema in .graphqls resource and create Resolver classes and you're done.  To get a working test example up and running took about 10 minutes.

Comment: I don't agree on all the disadvantages, infact it saves you alot of time check out  this post https://xalitech.com/graphql-how-to-convince-your-boss/

Answer (score 67):

I have found some important [concerns for anyone considering using GraphQL](https://labs.getninjas.com.br/pain-points-of-graphql-7e83ba5ddef7), and up until now the main points are:

**Query In Indefinite Depth**: GraphQL cannot query in indefinite depth, so if you have a tree and want to return a branch without knowing the depth, you’ll have to do some pagination.

**Specific Response Structure**: In GraphQL the response matches the shape of the query, so if you need to respond in a very specific structure, you'll have to add a transformation layer to reshape the response.

**Cache at Network Level**: Because of the commonly way GraphQL is used over HTTP (A POST in a single endpoint), cache at network level becomes hard. A way to solve it is to use Persisted Queries.

**Handling File Upload**: There is nothing about file upload in the GraphQL specification and mutations doesn’t accept files in the arguments. To solve it you can upload files using other kind of APIs (like REST) and pass the URL of the uploaded file to the GraphQL mutation, or inject the file in the execution context, so you’ll have the file inside the resolver functions.

**Unpredictable Execution**: The nature of GraphQL is that you can query combining whatever fields you want but, this flexibility is not for free. There are some concerns that are good to know like Performance and N+1 Queries.

**Super Simple APIs**: In case you have a service that exposes a really simple API, GraphQL will only add an extra complexity, so a simple REST API can be better.

Comment: For indefinite depth, I resort to JsonType responses. It's not strongly typed, so you need to check inputs, but it can be very handy.

Comment: REST always had N+1 Queries problem. The only difference is that by the design REST disallows backend to even attempt to resolve the issue. Instead it pushes the problem on the frontend.

Comment: https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec - file uploads in graphql are now widely supported

Answer (score 46):

This biggest problem that I see with graphQL i.e if you are using with relational database is with **joins**.

1. The fact that you can allow/disallow a few fields makes joins non-trivial(not simple). Which leads to extra queries.
2. Also Nested queries in graphql leads to circular queries and can **crash the server**. Extra care has to be taken.
3. **Rate limiting** of calls becomes difficult coz now the user can fire multiple queries in one call.

**TIP**: Use facebook's dataloader to reduce the number of queries in case of javascript/node

Comment: 1. How are selected fields relevant to join operations?
2. Not if you use a data loader.
3. You can parse and assign `cost` to the request. Also this is not a concern if you are using predefined queries, where the client only sends the ID.

Comment: agreed with 2. With 3 its bit of extra work and more importantly ppl need to be aware.

Comment: 2. This is not true anymore as you can use a lot of tools to protect your server. For example a link: https://www.howtographql.com/advanced/4-security/
Timeouts, limit on complexity and depth. So it's like the same as you'll say that your REST will be possible to DDoS if you won't use rate limiter. Things changed

Comment: updated point 2

Answer (score 16):

It's getting better and better each year, and as for now, the [community](https://graphql.org/community/) of GraphQL is growing, and as a result, there are many more solutions to a lot of problems that were highlighted in other answers before. But to admit what is still holding companies from throwing all resources to GraphQL I'd like to list some issues and solutions followed by unsolved ones.

- *Cache at Network Level* - as [Bruno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8391562/bruno-soares) said it's Persisted Queries
  and of course you can cache on a client and nobody stops you to use caching on database level or even Redis. But of course as GraphQL has only one endpoint and each query is different - it's much more complicated to do this type of caching than with REST.
- *Nested queries in GraphQL leads to circular queries and can crash the
  server* - not a problem anymore with a vast variety of solutions.
  Some of them are listed [here](https://www.howtographql.com/advanced/4-security/)
- *Handling File Upload* - we have already [lots](https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-client) of [solutions](https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-upload) for it

But there are couple more cases which can be counted as disadvantages:

- ***boilerplate excessiveness*** ( by this I mean, for the creating for example new query you need to define schema, resolver and inside the resolver to explicitly say GraphQL how to resolve your data and fields inside, on the client side create query with exactly fields related to this data)
- ***error handling*** - I need to say that it's more related to comparison with REST. It's possible here with [apollo](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/error-handling.html) but at the
  same time it's much more complicated than in REST
- ***authentication and authorization*** - but as I said community is increasing with outstanding speed and there are [already](https://github.com/kkemple/graphql-auth)
  [couple](https://blog.apollographql.com/authorization-in-graphql-452b1c402a9) [of](https://blog.pusher.com/handling-authentication-in-graphql/) [solutions](https://hackernoon.com/easy-peasy-graphql-authentication-and-authorization-using-schema-directives-f28f1845da20) for this goal.

To sum up, GraphQL is just a tool for specific goals and for sure it's not a silver bullet to all problems and of course not a replacement for REST.

Answer (score 5):

It's really great to have a single endpoint and expose all the data. I find below points to be considered for GraphQL:

1. Implementation of File Download / Upload gets tricky (converting to string might not be a best option for large files)
2. A lot of boilerplate and schema code at both frontend and backend.
3. Follow and support pagination provided in the GraphQL specification.
4. Allow custom order and prioritizing logic for ordering of fields. Example if we fetch users data and associated groups and roles. A user can multi sort the data based on username, group name or role name.
5. Authentication and Authorization would be dependent on the backend framework.
6. Ensure the backend optimization and Database support to fire single query for each graphql command might get tricky.

Also, one should consider the Pros after its implementation :

1. Very flexible to support new items and update existing behaviour.
2. Easy to add conditions using arguments and custom ordering once implemented
3. Use a lot of custom filters and get rid of all the actions that needs to be created example a user can have id, name, etc as arguments and perform the filtering. Additionally the filters can be applied on the groups in the users as well.
4. Ease of testing API  by creating files containing all the GraphQL queries and mutations.
5. Mutations are straightforward and easy to implement once understood the concept.
6. Powerful way to fetch multiple depths of data.
7. Support of Voyager and GraphiQL UI or Playground makes it easy to view and use.
8. Ease of documentation while defining the schema with valid description methods.

Answer (score 4):

I think graphql for the moment must be part of the backend architecture, for file upload you still hit a regular api

Comment: https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec - file uploads in graphql are now widely supported