# Difference between Graphql with non-Graphql React-Mongoose App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql

Why should I use graphql if I setup a react frontend and mongo db backend?
And Why should i put graphql server between mongo db and react?

Comment: There is no "should". GraphQL is a choice if it suits your needs. There is a plenty of good information [here](https://graphql.github.io/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't mention what is your alternative API style I will just assume it's REST. GraphQL gives you many features a plain old REST api won't have out of the box.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40691965/671457) is probably the best answer listing advantages and disadvantages of both.
You already have validation(via mongoose schemas), but using GQL you can get:

- excellent documentation for your API generated for you
- avoid underfetching/overfetching on frontend
- ability to batch FE requests easily
- you can tap into a very rich ecosystem of GraphQL tooling which only gets better as time passes
- easier testing-you can just execute your graphql queries on backend even without sending them over the network saving a little bit of performance overhead

I believe you should use GraphQL for any non trivial API, because it adds ton of typesafety and the price you pay as a developer is very low.