# If this Facebook Graph API is restful

Tags: rest, facebook-graph-api, restful-architecture

Facebook has an API to get your photos:

```
GET graph.facebook.com
  /me/photos
```

/me/ is a shortcut for the Id of the person logged in. Is that introducing state into the session and therefore is it restful?

Would it not be more restful to do:

```
/user/1234/photos
```

and then have some security layer to make sure only users with the appropriate token can access that URL?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api

Noticing some other places use this pattern. For example:

Stripe do this for GET all coupons:

```
GET https://api.stripe.com/v1/coupons
```

Paypal do this for all payments:

```
GET /v1/payments/payment
```

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/

Comment: /me has nothing to do with who can access what. It is simply a shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

GraphQL is not restful, I tried to sum this up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41141577/graphql-or-rest/41141829#41141829).

The `/me` does not necessarily introduce state, because the id for `me` could be in the headers, so the serverside can still be stateless.

> Is that introducing state into the session and therefore is it
>   restful?

In fact statelessness is a constraint for rest, so you would have to rephrase your question to "... therefore is it **not** restful"

But REST relies heavily on URIs, so this shortcut circumvents being transparent in the URI, what is not the best idea according to restful principles.

Answer (score 2):

REST IS a concept/approach/way to provide interoperability between computer systems.

REST IS NOT a standard, approved by a committee/organization in terms of strict regulations.

While there are architectural constraints, recommendations, unwritten rules, common solutions, you can't truly affirm this *is rest* or this *is not rest*. Everyone design its service as he thinks it's better.

Graph API is not exactly REST, they are a bit just different things/meanings.

Related to FB `/me` they said:

> The /me node is a special endpoint that translates to the user_id of
>   the person (or the page_id of the Facebook Page) whose access token is
>   currently being used to make the API calls.

As this URI depends on authenticated user, what's the problem with it?

Related to PayPal, I think You prefer `/v1/payments/payment` instead of `/v1/payments/35/payment`, but the same app deployed to another customer will be `/v1/payments/69/payment` or a logout like `/v1/user/35/logout`.

It's all about convenience.